# How are disc backups more useful than memory backups in KVM/QEMU

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh

So, I have to take disc snapshots of a VM but I cannot comprehend why are they useful and better than memory snapshots as said by a lot of people.

Suppose we have a computation going on, we take a disc snapshot and the system fails. Now, when we restore how do we automatically resume the computation even if we have to do it from the start since we were not taking memory backups. Is there any way to resume the computations automatically that were going before? The half computation can be lost but it should atleast start again.

Comment: Who said that and it what context?  Most computing these days is transactional in nature and has very short lived computations that don't benefit very much form memory snapshots - what you really want to have is a consistent disk state to resume from there. Doing long-running computations is a very different model and it might benefit from memory snapshots a lot more, but like with non-virtual hardware, you really ought to write checkpoints in regular intervals to resume from there if at all possible in your computational model.

Comment: The context is cloud computing and the computation can be long as well as short. Which would be a better way of snapshotting in this context?

Comment: If the software has no support for writing checkpoints to disk during computation, then you have to do memory snapshots.

Comment: There are multiple VM's so I will have to do synchronization myself since in a distributed environment, clocks are not synchronized. Right?

Comment: You can restart whatever was running the same way it was running initially. Backup/restore is a disaster recovery action, meaning it will pretty much always be an emergency requiring your manual involvement. As for the usefulness of memory snaps, it is highly dubious, since you will be restoring your workload with a significant time skew which might wack the whole thing out of shape anyhow. And again, backups are for emergency situations, better focus on consistent disk backups than waste time, disk space and effort on ram snaps

Comment: Do you have the installing the VM on a snapshotting filesystem?